# Google Ads scripts to remove sitelinks when they expire

Tags: google-ads-script

Hello wonderful people,

I am a noob in google ads scripts trying to write a script that automatically removes a sitelink when their end date lies in the past. (In my company we have a lot of promotions and we have a lot of sitelinks per campaigns).

I wrote this code and it works but it does absolutely nothing, can someone help me?

Thx a lot!

```
function main() {

   var date =  new Date();

   var campaign = AdsApp.campaigns()

    .withCondition("CampaignName = 'YOUR CAMPAIGN NAME HERE'")

    .get()

    .next();

   var campaignSitelinkDate = campaign.extensions()

     .sitelinks().getEndDate;

   var campaignSitelinkSelector = campaign.extensions()

     .sitelinks();

   /*.withCondition("Status = ENABLED") */

   /*.withCondition("CampaignStatus = PAUSED") */

   /*.forDateRange("YESTERDAY"); */

 

var campaignSitelinkIterator = campaignSitelinkSelector.get();

/* var campaignSitelinkDate = campaignSitelinkSelector.getEndDate;  */

if (campaignSitelinkIterator.hasNext() || (campaignSitelinkDate < date) ) {

   var campaignSitelink = campaignSitelinkIterator.next()

   campaignSitelinkSelector.removeSitelink;

 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `method` and `iterator` correctly.

```js
function main() {
    var date =  new Date();
    var campaign = AdsApp.campaigns()
        .withCondition("CampaignName = 'YOUR CAMPAIGN NAME HERE'")
        .get()
        .next();

    var campaignSitelinkSelector = campaign.extensions()
        .sitelinks();
    /*.withCondition("Status = ENABLED") */
    /*.withCondition("CampaignStatus = PAUSED") */
    /*.forDateRange("YESTERDAY"); */
    var campaignSitelinkIterator = campaignSitelinkSelector.get();

    if (campaignSitelinkIterator.hasNext()) {
        var campaignSitelink = campaignSitelinkIterator.next()
        var campaignSitelinkDate = campaignSitelink.getEndDate();
        if (campaignSitelinkDate < date) {
            campaign.removeSitelink(campaignSitelink);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hey Thx a lot I managed in the end to make it work and yes the problem was that I was not using method and iterator correctly.

Thx a bunch! Take care

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final version of the script that I've been using since a couple of months without issues if anyone stumbles on this topic and wants to copy paste it:

```
    function main() {
  
 var campaignSelector = AdsApp
     .campaigns()
     .withCondition("CampaignStatus = 'ENABLED'")
     .withCondition("CampaignName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE 'CONDITION'");
  
 var campaignIterator = campaignSelector.get();
 while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
   var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
   

   

 var campaignSitelinkSelector = campaign
     .extensions()
     .sitelinks();
   

   var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT + 4", "'year='yyyy,' month='MM,' day='dd"); 
 
  

   var campaignSitelinkIterator = campaignSitelinkSelector.get();
   
   
   while (campaignSitelinkIterator.hasNext()) {
   var campaignSitelink = campaignSitelinkIterator.next();
   var sitelinkEndDate = campaignSitelink.getEndDate();
   
   
     if (sitelinkEndDate != (null)) {
       
   var sitelinkEndDateYear = sitelinkEndDate.year.toString();
   var sitelinkEndDateMonth = (sitelinkEndDate.month<10) ? "0" + sitelinkEndDate.month : sitelinkEndDate.month.toString();
   var sitelinkEndDateDay = (sitelinkEndDate.day<10) ? "0" + sitelinkEndDate.day : sitelinkEndDate.day.toString();
   var sitelinkEndDateSum = sitelinkEndDateYear + '-' + sitelinkEndDateMonth +'-' + sitelinkEndDateDay;  
   
       
   
   var endDate = new Date(sitelinkEndDateSum)
   var endDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(endDate, "GMT + 4", "'year='yyyy,' month='MM,' day='dd");
    


       if (endDateFormatted < today) {
       
 
       campaign.removeSitelink(campaignSitelink)
       
       }      
}  
}
} 
}
```